# How does Linux handle DST (daylight saving time?

Tags: linux, database, dst, rhel

**How does linux handle daylight saving time (DST)**

**Does the swich  happen instantly, like 3'o clock swiched instantly to 2'o clock ?**
**or it changes slowly**
I ask you this becouse i have large date base on my servers and if this swich happens instantly one hour on entryes in the data base will pe owerwritten

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It changes instantly:

```
Sun 26 Oct 03:59:56 EEST 2014
Sun 26 Oct 03:59:57 EEST 2014
Sun 26 Oct 03:59:58 EEST 2014
Sun 26 Oct 03:59:59 EEST 2014
Sun 26 Oct 03:00:00 EET 2014
Sun 26 Oct 03:00:01 EET 2014
Sun 26 Oct 03:00:02 EET 2014
Sun 26 Oct 03:00:03 EET 2014
Sun 26 Oct 03:00:04 EET 2014
Sun 26 Oct 03:00:05 EET 2014
Sun 26 Oct 03:00:06 EET 2014
Sun 26 Oct 03:00:07 EET 2014
Sun 26 Oct 03:00:08 EET 2014
```

This is done on a test machine, and it switched immediately.

Answer (score 5):

> I ask you this becouse i have large date base on my servers and if this swich happens instantly one hour on entryes in the data base will pe owerwritten

That suggests you're writing the *local* time into the database. Regardless of how Linux handles it (and I believe it will do as you say, given that that's how time zones work, basically), you almost certainly *shouldn't* be writing the local time into your database.

If you write the UTC time instead, then you don't need to care about which time zone your systems are set to, or DST effects. You won't get odd situations where an event X which happened after an event Y is actually recorded with an earlier time, nor will there be any ambiguities. You can adjust the stored time to the local time zone when *presenting* the data should you wish - and you can do that into any time zone you please.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's recommended to store time data using Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) which doesn't have DST.

Convert from local timezone (and other locale issues) when going into and out of the database. Otherwise you have to store the timezone for for all the times in your database (explicitly or implicitly). Deal with the conversions seem annoying at first, but when you start dealing with users in different timezones you have to do it anyway. So having an a standardized DST-less time is handy in the long run.

As to your current issue, I'm not how to handle it. Since I've always dealt with UTC data, it just doesn't come up.

Comment: You should at least have answer the question (how does it handle DST) instead of only tackle the database problem exposed.

Comment: The question is how do they solve their problem, which is dealing with timezone-based data in their database when daylight saving hits. Focusing on how linux handles daylight saving (especially in terms of how quickly does the change happen) is not a good way to look at it. Regardless, the question/answer/accepted answer is 3 years ago. Go back in time and provide a better answer if you disagree, your comment doesn't add anything useful @ManuH

Comment: I found this question by searching how linux deal with DST as a general question and not how to manage databases. I hardly find the answer here. Thus I think tackling the answer must be done in each answer (in addition to helping people). The question is "how do linux deal with DST" and this is how it will first appear

Comment: Nothing can address everything. This question asks about DST in a narrow context which the accepted answer, answered to the question-asker's satisfaction. Those the problem the asker was dealing with is better dealt with by my answer (or the higher ranked answer which more does a better job of spelling out what I meant in my answer). Without more information I don't even know what information you want from the question "how does linux deal with DST". If you search the linux + dst tags, excluding the database tag, you might the information you're looking for. Limits of keyword search, afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might try:

Adding a trigger for you DST-sensitive data to be converted into
UTC time based.